# Styling RSS feed in CSS

Tags: php, css

I have the following RSS feed:

https://jsfiddle.net/yhtf36a1/

Right now, it gets displayed one below the other.

How do I use CSS to make it display two items per row, so that it looks like the following? [image]

I tried using `display:inline-block` but that didn't work.

Comment: use `Flex-box`.

Comment: create a parent div with 100% width then create child divs with 50% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
*{font-family:arial}
.rssRow{display:flex}
.entry-wrapper{display:inline-block; margin:.25em;background:#f3f3f3; border:3px solid #f1f1f1; background:#FFF;padding:10px;border-radius:5px;}
.entry-wrapper:hover{background:#edfdff;border:3px solid #f4f4f4}
.entry-image{float:left;}
.entry-text{float:left;}
.entry-title h4{margin:0; font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;}
.entry-title h4 a {color:#333; text-decoration:none;}
.entry-title h4 a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.entry-date{color:#999; padding-bottom:.75em;font-size:.75em}
```

Preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/yhtf36a1/3/

Let me know for any query on this

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```
.entry-wrapper {
  float:left;
  width: 48%;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 1%
}
```

See the example here: [jsfiddle.net/GillesCoeman/5e8z00z1](https://jsfiddle.net/GillesCoeman/5e8z00z1/)